# Flutter define buttonstyle globally

Tags: flutter, button, styles

so I would like to define my buttonstyles globally so that I can access them all at once.
I have enabled this for TextStyle like this:

```
abstract class ThemeText {
  static const TextStyle exampleStyle= TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 40,
      height: 0.5,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);
}
```

and when I access it in my text like this:

```
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                child: Text("Test",
                style: ThemeText.progressHeader,),
)
```

It works like a charm.

Now I want to do the same with my ButtonStyle:

```
TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
        child: Text("Test!"),
)
```

However if I try the same, it doesn't matter how I write it, I always get the
message "const variables must be initialized with a constant value". How do I format this for buttons so that it works just like the TextStyle?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In Flutter `Colors.green[900]`is not constant value. Using hex value might solve.

Comment: I already tried to go away from my example and keep it simple, according to the ButtonStyle class. So when I try:
abstract class ThemeButtons {
  static const ButtonStyle mainButton = ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty<Color>(Colors.green);
  );
}
it still throws an error. Maybe you have an idea for this one?

Comment: maybe basically removing const keyword can fix it, did you try that?

Comment: Damn, now I feel dumb. Thank you very much!